# What exists in the world according to the special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, time, models

Before I learned about special relativity, I thought that only one 3-dimensional state of the world exists. Then, like in game of chess, in one "turn" previous state is destroyed - and the new one is created. And this process is called "time".

Ok, that model was wrong. I read A LOT about special relativity. Now, I know a lot of facts. But I just can't build a model in my head with a similar clarity to what I had before.

What exists? Spacetime with objects inside it? Are there any changes happening? I know about eternalism, but that's philosophy, not physics. Please help, I'm really lost here!

Comment: In classical physics, particles and fields exist in spacetime. In quantum physics, quantum fields and their particle-like quanta exist in spacetime.

Comment: @Ghoster So, do the particles of dinosaurs "exist" the same way as particles of my current body? And millions of similar questions. I don't want to ask all of them, I want a model like I described before. Or is it even possible to formulate these things in such way?

Comment: I'm sorry but "what exists?" is a philosophical question. Physics cares about what we observe, and our ability to describe it, not what exists. For example, half of the [standard model](http://nuclear.ucdavis.edu/~tgutierr/files/sml2.pdf) comprises ghost fields, which are mathematical artifacts. Moreover, it is not even clear that the other fields exist in the absolute sense because, as Ghoster said, they exist *in* quantum physics. There really is no answer to your question (and particles are a relative concept as per QFT in curved space-time.)

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux are you saying there is NO simple "world model" that can be deduced from the special relativety formulas and definitions? All humans have a model in their heads... I don't believe physicists have nothing there, but practical formulas.

Comment: *do the particles of dinosaurs "exist" the same way as particles of my current body?* Most of the protons of the dinosaurs, for example, still exist. (I suppose some have been destroyed by cosmic rays.) Some of them might be in you now.

Answer (score 2):

Special relativity really doesn't change the rules in the way you might have thought. Locally, we all are moving along paths through spacetime, so you can still maintain your chess analogy in the sense that the position I occupy in spacetime moves from moment to moment (the weakness in your analogy is that as far as we know the movement is continuous, rather than discrete hops).

What might have confused you is the talk of a lack of common simultaneity, but you must be careful not to misinterpret that. Let me explain...

If you are stationary relative to another person some distance away, you and they share a common plane of simultaneity, so that their 'now' is the same as your 'now'. However, if they start moving away  from you, their plane of simultaneity tilts relative to yours, so their 'now' corresponds to a point in time earlier than your 'now'. It might slip back to yesterday, for example, but that doesn't make any difference to you- it doesn't mean that you go back in time, or that you still somehow exist yesterday- it just means that the other person uses a different t coordinate  to label your position in spacetime.

Comment: What about the universe as a whole? Can we take the spacetime and slice it on moment t? And then we can say that the whole universe at the time t was like (data)? I understand, that we may not be able to do it in practice ("lack of common simultaneity" as you have said), but in theory? Why not?

Comment: And according to your explanation, does it mean that there is an objective t coordinate for every event - we just can't get it?

Comment: Or maybe even like this: can we show (abstract) image of the spacetime (4d object) and say - "Look, here are you now ->"?

Comment: Yes you can consider a flat slice through spacetime, but it is just an arbitrary surface- it will bear no resemblance to what is 'now' in different parts of the Universe. Don't forget that spacetime is curved too, which complicates the picture. There is no absolute t coordinate system, but if you define an arbitrary origin you can label events with time coordinates in a meaningful way locally, but the curvature of spacetime means that you can't extrapolate over all the Universe in a simple way.